# What is the correct way to handle the AQuery (android-query) download result?

Tags: java, android, multithreading, android-query, aquery

Sorry if I missed something obvious, I tried really hard but didn't find any clue to answer my question.

So, my task is to download several images using their URLs and store them in some folder. I tried different approaches but for several reasons I decided I should use AQuery for this.
The download is actually done in IntentService which is started from the activity or from AlarmManager. The part where I download images is a for loop for downloading the required amount of images from the generated URLs:

```
for (int i=0; i < required; i++) {
    url = makeURL(i);
    aq.download(url, imgDir, new AjaxCallback() {
        @Override
        public void callback(String url, Object object, AjaxStatus status) {
            super.callback(url, object, status);
            File file = (File) object;
            if (file.length() < 300 * 1024) {  //just an example test
                file.delete();
            }
        }
    });
```

AQuery starts a separate thread for each download so the code continues to execute before I can get any result. The problem is that images can be broken or do not fit for other reasons so I do the test after each download in a callback method. If the image does not pass one of the tests I delete the file and need to redownload the image from another URL. But since all downloads are done in an independent threads I can't catch the result of the downloads in the same IntentService where I have all the "spare" URLs.

Since my IntentService is a background thread itself I think I can do all the downloads in that thread, check the file after each download and try another URL if it's bad.

As I understand, I have two options here:

- find a way to make aq.download use the same thread
- don't use AQuery and take another approach for downloading

I would be very grateful for an advice. My experience is still very limited to make the correct decision. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Its better to just move-on to library that has more user base and supports multithreading well